# Excel VBA - advanced filter - highlight rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a macro to do an advanced filter on a range with a fixed number of columns but variable number of rows.  I would then like to highlight the visible rows and clear the filter.

Through research, I've come up with this code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 65535
```

Strangely, it was working but stopped when I changed some of the filter criteria.  So something is going on that I don't understand.  I now get run-time error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error."

More code / larger snippet:

```
Sheets("Filters").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="WBS Element", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Set CritRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
Sheets("Data").Activate
DataRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=CritRange

Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Font.Bold = True

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 65535

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Comment: What happens if you `Set CritRange = Sheets("Filters").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))`

Comment: just tried it - still got the application-defined or object-defined error (1004) on the line where i try to highlight the visible cells.

i should also add that if i remove the "activesheet." from this line, i get a different error (method 'range' of object '_global' failed).

Comment: Hmmm that line does not cause any failure for me. Create a new subroutine with ONLY that line of code.  `ActiveSheet.Range("A2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 65535` Run it on any worksheet. Does the error still happen?  I'm suspecting a typo in your code that is not present in the snippet you pasted here.

Comment: It seems like you could use conditional formatting for this. It's built in, and you can control it via VBA in case you want the parameters to change.

Comment: @David Zemens Thanks for the idea.  I created a new subroutine with just that line of code, and still am getting the same error.  I copy/pasted the code from my macro directly into my post above, and also tried copy/pasting your snippet into my macro.  For reference:  

    Sub DataFilter()

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 65535
 
    End Sub

Comment: OK now it's erroring for me on an empty worksheet... the problem is definitely related to the range definition I think. Let me figure out your solution and I'll give you some steps to resolve this.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try out either of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a solution while putzing.  Basically, I took the one line of code and multiplexed it out into several lines for each thing I wanted to do.  The problem seemed to come from how I was setting my range... this works for me:

```
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 10)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = 65535
```

Answer (score 0):

OK try this. There was some problems with the range assignment.  You don't need `Cells(Rows.Count,1)` since you only care about the row # you can just use `.Rows.Count`.

I also think it useful to use object variables (like `filterRange` in the example below). It will make your code a lot easier to interpret as you move forward.

```
Sub HighlightRows()
Dim filterRange As Range

With ActiveSheet
   '// first define the range
    Set filterRange = _
        .Range("A2:J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    '// now, manipulate the range as needed
    filterRange.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 65535
End With


End Sub
```

You should be able to modify this to fit within your subroutine, or you can keep this as a stand-alone subroutine and call it by name, like this:

```
Sub YourSubRoutine()
Sheets("Filters").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="WBS Element", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Set CritRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
Sheets("Data").Activate
DataRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=CritRange

Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Font.Bold = True

'// Call a subroutine to do the highlighting:
Call HighlightRows

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub
```